# Brew updated mongodb services error message on listing

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed the mongodb on mac version 3.2 and inserted data working fine. Had to update do version 3.6 and now the mongodb services using 3.6 dont work.

```
➜  ~ brew services restart mongodb-community@3.6
Stopping `mongodb-community@3.6`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community@3.6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-c
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@3.6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-c
➜  ~ brew services                                           
Name                  Status  User            Plist
mongodb-community@3.2 stopped                 
mongodb-community@3.6 error   /Users/fernandocorreia/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-
```

Anyone has any tip